# get_footer can't find any variables set in functions.php

Tags: functions, array

footer.php can't find any variables I set in functions.php, I've tried a global (urggh) and object array like so:

```
$foo = (object)array("bar" => "test text");
```

It works within page template, just not in the header or footer, does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem.

Your variable in `functions.php` is not in scope where you are trying to use it in your footer.

To make this work declare the variable global in `functions.php`

```
global $tst;
$tst = 'd00d';
```

And then pull it in with the `global` keyword when you need to use it.

```
global $tst;
echo $tst;
```

Or, even better, ***rethink things so that you don't need the global at all***-- maybe build a class or a function with a static variable.

Comment: Page templates run in the global scope, but header.php and footer.php are included from function calls to get_header() and get_footer(), and thus are indeed in a function scope. You will need to declare globals in them if you wish to access them there.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question really, I already used globals as I said, and had to set them again in the header/footer for it to work, I'll just consider this as life. I went ahead and registered my own class and bumped into the same issue again, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing exactly but what I posted does work. I have done it many times. You must be manipulating the globals incorrectly somehow. You haven't posted exactly how your code is written/organized so it is hard to say a lot more than that.